# Which design pattern can I apply for handling command application?

Tags: c#

If I have an application of handling commands and processing, is there a suitable design pattern should I use because currently I have a long switch case statements?

```
switch(command)

{
   case ACK : // process(); break;
   case NAK : // process(); break;
   case POLL: // process(); break;
   ...
}
```

Comment: See http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do a few things here. If it's really as simple as tying a command to a value, you can use a simple `Dictionary` to tie a command name to a delegate that it executes, like:

```
private static IDictionary<string, Action> _actionsByCommand;

static MyClass() {
    _actionsByCommand[ACK] = Acknowledge;
    _actionsByCommand[POLL] = Poll;
}

private static void Acknowledge() { }
private static void Poll() { }

static void Main() {
    string command = ...;
    _actionsByCommand[command]();
}
```

Or instead of delegates, you can define classes for each of your commands with a shared base class or interface, and have a `Go` method of some kind that executes. This would give you the benefit of having additional properties or values tied to each command, if you need it down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have three methods with the same signature.

```
public Func<string, int> Ack = (i) => return 1;
public Func<string, int> Nack= (i) => return 1; 
public Func<string, int> Poll = (i) => return 1;
```

and you want to call them without case statement.

```
public int Call(string commandName)
{
    //Find method
    var method = this.GetType().GetFields().First(x=>x.Name == commandName);
    if (method == null) return null;
    //Convert it to Func
    var m = (Func<string, int>) method.GetValue(this);
    return m.Invoke("");
}
```

you will use it like.

```
new MethodRunner().Call("Ack");
```